# How to unmount inactive screens in bottom tab navigator react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Im using react-navigation for react-native. Is there an option to make that inactive tab screens get unmounted like unmountInactiveRoutes: true in DrawerNavigator?? I cant find something like unmountInactiveRoutes for BottomTabNavigator.

I have two stacknavigators inside a BottomTabNavigator and I want to unmount them automatically.

- BottomTabNavigator

  - Stack1

    - Screen
    - Screen
  - Stack2

    - Screen
    - Screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I don't know if you can unmount components that are inactive personally I did not find it however this is my workaround `withNavigationFocus(FocusStateLabel)`
and if `isFocused` is false. returning null. So this will give you more or less what you are looking for. If isFocused is true, you'll render what you usually render. If false you'll return null. resulting in the unmounting of your components

Some reference https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html

Comment: And for react-navigation 5.x?

Answer (score 36):

You can unmount screens in bottom tab by adding option in navigation screenOptions (or in Tab.Navigator screenOptions):

```
unmountOnBlur: true
```

You can do it in Tab & Drawer Navigations but not in Stack Navigation.

And you can also add unmount individual screen by adding same option in Tab or Drawer Screen option.

Comment: This should be specified in Tab.Navigator screenOptions. Then all tabs will remount on every switching between tabs (correct behaviour for me)

Answer (score 7):

I tried Ubaid’s answer it works. But you can try this one too:
Use

```
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
useEffect(() => {
    // Do whatever you want to do when screen gets in focus
  }, [props, isFocused]);
```

It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Theres also a `useFocusEffect` hook which is basically the same thing but already packaged as a `useEffect`-like hook that can be imported from `@react-navigation/native`. Same result with less code :)

Comment: This is what i am finding..

Answer (score 1):

I found two way unmount.

1. First method is just trigger the unmount using `useFocusEffect`. With my experience this is not completely unmount component. It just trigger only unmount function to unsubscribe events.
   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-a-focus-event-listener
2. Second method is completely unmount component when the navigating. This one is working as react unmount.
   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{unmountOnBlur: true}}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

In your tab screens

```
const unMount = ()=>{
     //unmount what you want
}

useEffect(()=>{
     return unMount;
},[])
```

Modify your code with this

Comment: The return of useEffect not apply in this case because that is to handle the unmount event emitted by the Screen, Braven is looking for how to emit that event when the screen is not focused by react navigation